# Firefox could not display SVG img properly

Tags: svg

In desktop version of Firefox (version 56.0), the SVG image was displayed incorrectly.
For example, with the following SVG image for twitter logo, it shows something that not even close to twitter logo. The same SVG image is displayed properly in other browsers, (IE11, Edge, Chrome, etc.). Is this a bug in Firefox? or there is a workaround to make it work? (two screenshots for working and not-working pages in attachment)

```
<img  style="width:640px; height:640px;" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2032%2032%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2032%2032%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%2355ACEE%22%20d%3D%22M32%2C6.4c-1.2%2C0.5-2.4%2C0.9-3.8%2C1c1.4-0.8%2C2.4-2.1%2C2.9-3.6c-1.3%2C0.8-2.7%2C1.3-4.2%2C1.6c-1.2-1.3-2.9-2.1-4.8-2.1%2Cc-3.6%2C0-6.6%2C2.9-6.6%2C6.6c0%2C0.5%2C0.1%2C1%2C0.2%2C1.5C10.3%2C11.1%2C5.5%2C8.5%2C2.2%2C4.5c-0.6%2C1-0.9%2C2.1-0.9%2C3.3c0%2C2.3%2C1.2%2C4.3%2C2.9%2C5.5%2Cc-1.1%2C0-2.1-0.3-3-0.8c0%2C0%2C0%2C0.1%2C0%2C0.1c0%2C3.2%2C2.3%2C5.8%2C5.3%2C6.4c-0.6%2C0.1-1.1%2C0.2-1.7%2C0.2c-0.4%2C0-0.8%2C0-1.2-0.1%2Cc0.8%2C2.6%2C3.3%2C4.5%2C6.1%2C4.6c-2.2%2C1.8-5.1%2C2.8-8.2%2C2.8c-0.5%2C0-1.1%2C0-1.6-0.1c2.9%2C1.9%2C6.4%2C2.9%2C10.1%2C2.9c12.1%2C0%2C18.7-10%2C18.7-18.7%2Cc0-0.3%2C0-0.6%2C0-0.8C30%2C8.9%2C31.1%2C7.7%2C32%2C6.4z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E" />
```

[Working SVG in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl01W.png)

[Not-working SVG in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oyGF.png)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to make the SVG img to display correctly in Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is invalid. Commas are only allowed between numbers so -2.1,c is invalid and a UA should stop parsing there. Firefox is correct and the other UAs are not per the SVG specification.

If you decoded the data URL to a file and viewed the file directly you'd have seen the error logged in the Firefox console.

Removing the invalid commas fixes things. If this SVG was produced by a tool you should get the tool fixed.

```html
<img  style="width:640px; height:640px;" src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2032%2032%22%20enable-background%3D%22new%200%200%2032%2032%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%2355ACEE%22%20d%3D%22M32%2C6.4c-1.2%2C0.5-2.4%2C0.9-3.8%2C1c1.4-0.8%2C2.4-2.1%2C2.9-3.6c-1.3%2C0.8-2.7%2C1.3-4.2%2C1.6c-1.2-1.3-2.9-2.1-4.8-2.1c-3.6%2C0-6.6%2C2.9-6.6%2C6.6c0%2C0.5%2C0.1%2C1%2C0.2%2C1.5C10.3%2C11.1%2C5.5%2C8.5%2C2.2%2C4.5c-0.6%2C1-0.9%2C2.1-0.9%2C3.3c0%2C2.3%2C1.2%2C4.3%2C2.9%2C5.5c-1.1%2C0-2.1-0.3-3-0.8c0%2C0%2C0%2C0.1%2C0%2C0.1c0%2C3.2%2C2.3%2C5.8%2C5.3%2C6.4c-0.6%2C0.1-1.1%2C0.2-1.7%2C0.2c-0.4%2C0-0.8%2C0-1.2-0.1c0.8%2C2.6%2C3.3%2C4.5%2C6.1%2C4.6c-2.2%2C1.8-5.1%2C2.8-8.2%2C2.8c-0.5%2C0-1.1%2C0-1.6-0.1c2.9%2C1.9%2C6.4%2C2.9%2C10.1%2C2.9c12.1%2C0%2C18.7-10%2C18.7-18.7c0-0.3%2C0-0.6%2C0-0.8C30%2C8.9%2C31.1%2C7.7%2C32%2C6.4z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
```

Comment: From the working code snippet (decoded), I still see "18.7-18.7,c0-0.3". Isn't it also an invalid commas?

Comment: @HarverYang oops, yes I missed one. Looks like it didn't make too much of a difference but I've corrected that now.